# useState wouldn't work asynchronously (array)

Tags: reactjs

I would like to reflect state asynchronously. But when I add a value, it is not reflected asynchronously. How can I solve this problem?

```
const [values, setValues] = useState<string[]>([])
const [input, setInputs] = useState<string>()

const add = useCallback(() => {
  if(!input) return
  values.push(input)
  setValues(values)
}, [input, values])

...
<input onChange={() => setInput(e.target.value) />
<button onClick={() => add()}>Add</button>

// not displayed asynchrnously
{values && values.map((value, idx) => {
  return (
    <div key={idx}>{value}</div>         
  )
})}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting the existing state based on the previous state, the recommended way to do it is to send a callback function to the state setting function.

I have modified your `add` function to reflect this:

```
const add = useCallback(() => {
  if (input) {
    setValues(prev => [...prev, input])
  }
}, [input, setValues])
```

Also, your callback function for setting the input was missing the event parameter and had a typo. I have fixed both issues:

```
<input onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} />
```